# Two mod rewrite for one page .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to have two mod rewrite rules directing to one page? For example could I have:

*mysite.com/blog/15* AND
*mysite.com/blog/post-title*

both pointing to:
*mysite.com/blogpost.php?id=15*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's specific to "15" and "post-title", then yes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/15$ /blogpost.php?id=15 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/post-title$ /blogpost.php?id=15 [L]
```

If it's were "15: and "post-title" can be anything, then no.

There's no way mod_rewrite can know what id a post-title maps to unless it has access to the actual mapping (e.g. in a database). You can possibly use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) to define a map type and point it to a file or a script that can talk to a database, but the map has to be defined in the server/vhost config. Can't use it in an htaccess file.

You're better off just adding that functionality to the `blogpost.php` script and pass the title to it. for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([0-9]+)$ /blogpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /blogpost.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, your answer is really useful:)